# redirect to another form

Tags: php, forms, asp-classic

I have a basic html form that is on a site run by php.  I'm looking to redirect to another form and populate it with the first form's info but that site is running asp. I cannot populate these forms as the name attributes are different.  Take a look at the two form inputs:

Site 1:

```
<input
  type="text"
  id="username"
  name="username" <!-- Different names -->
  value="" />
```

Site 2:

```
<input
  class="txt"
  type="text"
  id="CreateNewAccountInfo_UserName"
  name="CreateNewAccountInfo.UserName" <!-- Different names -->
  value="" />
```

How do I populate form2 with form1 info when the name attribute on form2 has a . separator in it?

Comment: how are you passing the parameters from page to page?

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the data from the first form and put those into url parameters:

```
/somelink?param1=something&param2=something_else&param3...
```

In the asp page, grab the query parameters OnLoad():

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      var param1 = Request.QueryString["param1"];
      //etc
   }
}
```

After grabbing what you need from the QueryString, you can populate the controls on the serverside. Note you can also do this on the front end with jQuery, but I figured if you are using Asp.Net it would be easy enough to do this in the code-behind.